# Is it possible to tell a ControlTemplate resource to only apply itself to my inherited control?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, controltemplate

I am using a DevExpress GridControl and I have inherited a class from that.  The class is just a class in C# that adds some dependency properties, it has no XAML page.

In my `ResourceDictionary`, I have defined two elements:  a `ControlTemplate` that adds some buttons to the grid's search control, and a `Style` that adjusts that search control's margin/padding properties.  These are using `Key` identifiers that make them apply to every grid that I use.  But I really only want them to apply when that grid is of my inherited type.

How do I make those two elements apply themselves only to my inherited control, and not the base grid control?

Current top tag definitions:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{dxet:SearchControlThemeKey ResourceKey=Template, ThemeName=MyTheme}">

<Style x:Key="{dxgt:TableViewThemeKey ThemeName=MyTheme, ResourceKey=SearchPanelContentTemplate}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
```

Where `dxet` and `dxgt` are DevExpress namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward solution would probably be to declare those resource inside of your custom grid control's default `Style`:

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:MyGridControl"
       BasedOn="{x:Static dxg:GridControl}">

    <!-- TODO: Double check the BasedOn style key above. -->

    <!-- Put any *new* setters, triggers, etc. here. -->
    <!-- You'll already inherit the setters and triggers from the BasedOn style. -->

    <Style.Resources>

      <!-- Resources only visible in the context of your custom grid's style: -->

      <ControlTemplate x:Key="{dxet:SearchControlThemeKey ResourceKey=Template, ThemeName=MyTheme}" />

      <Style x:Key="{dxgt:TableViewThemeKey ThemeName=MyTheme, ResourceKey=SearchPanelContentTemplate}"
             TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" />

    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Put the above style in a **Themes\Generic.xaml** resource dictionary, located in the same assembly that declares your custom grid control.  That's the standard location where WPF will probe for default control styles.  If your `AssemblyInfo.cs` doesn't already contain such an entry, add this:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    // Where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
    // (used if a resource is not found in the page, or application
    // resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,

    // Where the generic resource dictionary is located
    // (used if a resource is not found in the page, app, or 
    // any theme specific resource dictionaries)                                 
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly 
)]
```

The result should be that instances of your custom grid will see the overridden resources, but instances of the standard `GridControl` will see the default versions.

Make sure you override the default style key for your custom grid:

```
static MyGridControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(MyGridControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyGridControl)));
}
```

---

#### Alternate Proposal

Did you consider using *attached* dependency properties to add new functionality to the existing grid control, instead of extending it with your own subclass?

Depending on what all you're doing, it might be better to declare a `GridExtensions` class that registers some attached properties, routed events, and class-level command handlers for your custom buttons.

Comment: Would this style wrapper also go in the `ResourceDictionary`, then?  Since the inherited control has no XAML, it's unclear where I would put this solution.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that your custom grid control would have its own default style, just as the standard grid control does.  You could base it off the default grid's style so inherit its property setters and triggers.  The style would go in a `Themes\Generic.xaml` resource dictionary, which is the standard location for default control styles.

Comment: That alternate approach is something I'll have to research, as that is currently way out of my league.  I've been into WPF for less than a year, so the "advanced" well is still pretty deep.  For now, I'll take a stab at the main idea. Thank you.